# SQL syntax error INSERT INTO

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO Group (Id, Nombre, Cerrado, PermisosLibres, PermisosAdministrados, Reciprocos, Chat, MinutosGrupo)
VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1');
```

I do not understand why this error occurs, I have watched many times and I see no failure.

[image]

I do not understand why this error occurs, I have watched many times and I see no failure.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group (Id, Nombre, Cerrado, PermisosLibres, PermisosAdministrados, Reciprocos, C' at line 1
```

Comment: `Group` is a keyword, you have to put backticks around it.

Comment: The clue really is in the error message. 'Near' is a euphemism for 'exactly at'. A better idea is to avoid reserved words altogether. There's only approx. 220 of them, so it's pretty easy to do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `Group` as a table name it is a reserved word. You need to use `Group` with backticks

Your insert statement should be:

```
INSERT INTO `Group` (Id, Nombre, Cerrado, PermisosLibres, PermisosAdministrados, Reciprocos, Chat, MinutosGrupo)
VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1');
```

Comment: Nope, he needs to use backticks. This is MySQL, not SQL Server.

Comment: ok, thanks @fancyPants - that's a terrible username by the way

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
INSERT INTO `Group` (`Id`, `Nombre`, `Cerrado`, `PermisosLibres`, `PermisosAdministrados`, `Reciprocos`, `Chat`, `MinutosGrupo`)
VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1');
```

**What added:**

Added `backticks` since `Group` is a reserved keyword in MySQL.